# How to ensure keyboard has the negative key for an HTML number input on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, input

I am developing a mobile application that requires negative numbers to be inputted. However, the mobile keyboard only has the keys [1-9.]. Is there a way to ensure the negative sign is present on the keyboard? I am using the Cordova framework.

Comment: Why not just affix a minus sign to the number the user enters with JavaScript?

Comment: I want to allow both negative and positive numbers.

Comment: Isn't this feature dependent on the virtual-keyboard your user has installed on his device? E.g on my Android, I have two different virtual-keyboards installed, and each gives different keys available for number inputs (but both give the `-` symbol).

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for a way to enter `-` sign using html input tag, try this

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric">
```

Although, this combination looks weird, it serves the purpose. You will be able to enter - sign in all major devices (including Samsung which otherwise creates problems). You can then parse it to number if you want the user to enter only valid numerics and show validation according to that.

Answer (score 1):

For cordova the keyboard is determined by the type of input.  I believe on most devices using the tel type will have an option for symbols such as a negative sign.

example:

```
<input type="tel">
```

If tel doesn't have what you are looking for then you are going to need to put in a text type of input.  Either way, the result of a tel type input is a string so you'll need to verify that the input provided is a number.

**Note: In the event the device doesn't have a tel type keyboard it will use the normal text keyboard instead.**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Not quite what I was hoping for, but it seems this might be my only choice.

Comment: Yea I can imagine it wasn't exactly what you were looking for, but exactly what you are looking for doesn't exist unfortunately.  Cordova is primarily just a bridge between the code and the phone's native functionality.  The keyboard on each phone most likely will vary.

Comment: It is too bad negative number input is not supported. You would imagine if your min value is set less than 0 that it would be present on the keyboard.